# Conda does not use activated env when running flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have installed my package (let's just call it "mypackage") using pip when the conda virtual env is activated. I can confirm that it's installed using pip list. However, when I try to run 'flask run', I got an error message "ImportError: No module named 'mypackage'". As I look at the traceback, flask cli does not correspond to my conda env though I do have activated my conda env. The traceback seems to say that flask is running in root env.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/home/borg/anaconda3/bin/flask", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(flask.cli.main())
  File "/home/borg/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 478, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "/home/borg/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 345, in main
    return AppGroup.main(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/borg/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 696, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/borg/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1060, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/borg/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 889, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/borg/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 534, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/borg/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/home/borg/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 534, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/borg/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 388, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "/home/borg/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 124, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/home/borg/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 148, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/home/borg/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 209, in load_app
    rv = locate_app(self.app_import_path)
  File "/home/borg/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 89, in locate_app
    __import__(module)
```

Comment: Can you see your package and flask in the output of the command: 'conda list' ?

Comment: @PriyankMehta Now I figure out what went wrong. I build another extremely simple project to test whether my files are correctly configured. Then I found that I can't run the app when I import flask.ext.security or flask_security.

Comment: So, installing flask-security in your conda environment should solve your issue

Comment: @PriyankMehta I remember having installed everything needed. But just to be sure, I deleted the virtual env and reinstall everything. Note that this time I use conda to install pip for my virtual env like "conda install pip -n myvirtualenv". Then use pip to install packages. Now it works well.